# Vector norms are only on column vectors? How about row vectors?

Tags: normed-spaces

When I studied on norms: vectors are defined by : $x\in R^n$.

Many books said $x$ is a column vector. (Also, define inner product $x^tx$.)

What I am curious about is : $||x|| =||x^t||$? (any) norms of vector and its transpose are the same.

We should see $||x^t||$ or calculate as like a column vector? or is it a matrix, and calculate like induced norm?

Comment: Norms can be defined on any (real) vector space

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah, then it doesn't matter if it is row vector or column vector? The result would be the same?

Comment: If you have a norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ on the space of column vectors, you can simply *define* a norm on the space of row vectors by $\Vert x^t\Vert:=\Vert x\Vert$. It's quite natural to do so. But you can also define entirely different norms on both spaces. So it really depends: which norms are we talking about? The ones which satisfy your condition by definition? Then certainly yes. Any other pair of norms? Then certainly no.

Comment: I think that this problem is quite simpler. «Vectors are defined by $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$», therefore a related question should be: does the definition $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ always represent a column vector? Or a row vector? Or either of them? And if  $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ **only** represents a column vector, how do you write a row vector with the same notation?

Comment: I believe that vectors are *row vectors* just because this way they are easier to handle when dealing with matrices. An $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ can be multiplied to an $n \times 1$ column vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$: $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{x}$ (while it would be impossible to multiply the same matrix to a row vector $1 \times n$, $\mathbf{x}^T$). But column vectors can be switched to row vectors while maintaining exactly the same features. I think that a column vector and its corresponding row vector are just two equivalent representations of the same object

Answer (score 1):

The elements $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ are just $n$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ and, a priori, neither row nor column vectors. If you use them for doing euclidean geometry, say, studying ellipses or spirals, then you usually use the norm
$$|x|:=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}\ .\tag{1}$$
When you are doing in fact linear algebra then you consider the points of the given "base space" $X:={\mathbb R}^n$ as column vectors and set up the standard matrix calculus. In this environment you sometimes also use norms, e.g., the above norm $(1)$, which then is  denoted $\|x\|_2$. In some cases you use other norms, e.g.,
$$\|x\|_1:=\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|,\qquad{\rm or}\qquad \|x\|_\infty:=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k|\ .$$
These norms refer to the "base space" $X$. To this space is associated its *dual* $X^*$ containing the linear functionals $\phi: \>X\to{\mathbb R}$. Such a functional appears as $$\phi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k\ ,$$ so that "datawise" this $\phi$ is again encoded by an $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=:a$. In matrix calculus this $n$-tuple $a$ is then a row vector (and is sometimes written $a^{\rm t}$, or similar). When we have some norm $\|\cdot\|$ on the base space $X$ the $\phi$ has automatically its *functional norm*
$$\|\phi\|:=\sup_{x\ne0}{|\phi(x)|\over\|x\|}\ .$$
When the norm in $X$ is the euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ then $\|\phi\|=\|a\|_2$ again, but when the norm in $X$ is $\|\cdot\|_1$ then the "associated" norm in $X^*$ is $\|\phi\|=\|a\|_\infty$. (The proof is an exercise.)